# Cannot run Rails server locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been messing around with my rails project a little too much and now i can no longer run my rails server locally.

I try to run it like norma with `rails server` but it does not start.

Please take a look at the stack below, maybe someone can point out where i am going wrong?

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.


Traceback (most recent call last):
        60: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
        59: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
        58: from /Users/linusmjorn/Documents/Projects/conference/conference/bin/spring:5:in `<top (required)>'
        57: from /Users/linusmjorn/Documents/Projects/conference/conference/bin/spring:5:in `tap'
        56: from /Users/linusmjorn/Documents/Projects/conference/conference/bin/spring:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
        55: from /Users/linusmjorn/Documents/Projects/conference/conference/bin/spring:8:in `require'
        54: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        53: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        52: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        51: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        50: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        49: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        48: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        47: from /Users/linusmjorn/Documents/Projects/conference/conference/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
        46: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        45: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        44: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        43: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        42: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        41: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        40: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        39: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        38: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        37: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
        36: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        35: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        34: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        33: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        32: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        31: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
        30: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
        29: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        28: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        27: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        26: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        25: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        24: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        23: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        22: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        21: from /Users/linusmjorn/Documents/Projects/conference/conference/config/application.rb:9:in `<main>'
        20: from /Users/linusmjorn/Documents/Projects/conference/conference/config/application.rb:11:in `<module:Conference>'
        19: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `inherited'
        18: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
        17: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
        16: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        15: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in `execute_hook'
        14: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in `with_execution_control'
        13: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in `block in execute_hook'
        12: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        11: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro.rb:23:in `load'
        10: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:36:in `load'
         9: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:42:in `each'
         8: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in `configuration'
         7: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:64:in `global_configuration'
         6: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in `raw_configuration'
         5: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in `block in raw_configuration'
         4: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:60:in `parse'
         3: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:277:in `load'
         2: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:390:in `parse'
         1: from /Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse_stream'
/Users/linusmjorn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 14 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
linusmjorn@Linuss-MBP-2 conference %
```

Any ideas? I'm even unsure as to what to google here.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the first line of the error. Check your Gemfile to see if `pg` is indeed listed twice

Comment: Thanks Max. It was indeed listed twice, i removed it but i still cannot start the server.

Comment: what is the other error? If it's something completely separate, you should make a new question about it

Comment: The actual error is from the figaro gem. The pg error is just a warning. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for possible clues in the error output:

1 - It's loading your application configuration:

```
20: from .../conference/conference/config/application.rb:11:in `<module:Conference>'
```

2 - From there it's loading **figaro**:

```
12: from .../gems/figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
```

3 - Figaro is parsing something:

```
 4: from .../figaro-1.2.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:60:in `parse'
```

4 - It's a YAML file (Psych is being used):

```
 ...psych.rb:456:in `parse':
```

5 - There's an error in this YAML file at line 14:

```
could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 14 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Now we can try to make a guess:

Figaro normally loads settings from `config/application.yml`. Have you checked for a typo there?

Answer (score 0):

> Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.

Gems are sometimes placed under groups (e.g. `test`, `development`, and `production`). That way you can run `bundle install` on specific groups ([Bundler docs reference](https://bundler.io/v1.5/groups.html)).

Groups are typically written in the following format:

```
group :development do
  gem 'example1', '~> 1.23'
  gem 'example2', '> 1.00'
  gem 'example3', '>= 2.34'
end
```

You can think of gems that are not placed under a group as being in the global group. This means that they are accessible within all the groups defined in `Gemfile`.

*What is likely happening here is that the `pg` gem is placed under the same group more than once.*

So **to possibly fix this**:

1. Go to `Gemfile`
2. Remove the extra `pg` gems that are sharing the same group (keep only one per group)
3. Run `bundle install`
4. Run `rails server`